# Add element to list or create it if null?

Tags: list, dictionary, groovy

I want to have a map that contains Lists as values. A working sample is this:

```
def someObject = 'foo'
def someMap = [:]
if (someMap['key'] == null) {
    someMap['key'] = [someObject]
} else {
    someMap['key'].add(someObject)
}
```

While this works, it's kind of annoying, because I need to differentiate between whether or not a list within the map has been created already. Does Groovy have a way to make this more "beautiful"?

Comment: it's not java, this is js.

Comment: Dont put tags on your question that dont matter!

Comment: This is not JS, it's Groovy, which lays on top of Java.

Comment: @user3216060 to be fair, it's nothing to do with Java though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
def someMap = [:].withDefault { [] }
```

Then

```
someMap['key'] << someObject
```